# Using iterators to modify array elements in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

The problem arise when I am trying to write an insert function that is suppose to move all elements in the array up at the specified location given by the iterator and then insert a new value into the array at the position given by the iterator.

The code is getting errors in the **insert** function with the following error:

> no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::basic_string [1000]' and 'std::basic_string')

I am new to using iterators, and I think that it is not possible to access array elements with pointers as indices. So I am not sure if there is another way to do this, or do I need to overload the [] operator to make it work some how?

```
template <class T>
class Vector {
    public:
        typedef T* iterator;
        Vector () {  }

        T& operator[](unsigned int i) {
           return items[i];
        }
          // T& operator[](iterator i) {
           //return items[*i];
        //}

        iterator begin () {
            return &items[0];
        }
        iterator end () { 
            return &items[used];
        }
        int size () { return used; }

        iterator insert (iterator position, const T& item) { 

            for(Vector<T>::iterator i=&items[998]; i>=position; i--)
            {
                items[*(i+1)]=items[*i];
            }
            items[*position]= item;

            return position;
        }
    private:
        T items[1000];
        int used=0;
};
```

Comment: `T items[1000];` is an C-Array not a `Vector<T>` so `Vector<T>::iterator i=&items[998];` is ill formed.

Comment: @RichardCritten `Vector<T>::iterator` has type `T*`. `&items[998]` has type `T*`. It should be compatible. (Did I overlook something?)

Comment: The previous comment in mind, in `insert()`: `i` is of type `T*`. `*i` as well as `*(i + 1)` has type `T&` (a reference to a `T`). So, the `items[*(i + 1)]` does not make sense. (If I got it right `*(i + 1) = *i;` would instead.)

Comment: @Scheff it just has to be `RandomAccessIterator` not necessarily a plain `T*` (it can be a class with operators) see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @RichardCritten Sorry, it's `Vector` not `std::vector`. I believe, OP tries to rebuild it for educational purpose.

Comment: @Scheff you are right - I need to read slower and more accurately.

Comment: [std::copy_backward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward) might interest you.

Comment: An iterator is not an index, and cannot be used as an index. An iterator is used as if it was a pointer. In your case it *is* a pointer. Use it as a pointer: `*position = item;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is problematic in the sense that it creates 1000 elements of type T, even if logically it is empty. Also, if there are more than 1000 insertions, then the upper elements are discarded.

As for the compilation issues, I have tries to compile the code with `Vector<int>` and it compiles fine, but crashes. For the same reason it crashes with `Vector<int>` it does not compile with `Vector<std::string>`. The Issue is with the type of `*i`, which is , i.e., `std::string` in the case of `Vector<std::string>`. Either use iterator all the way, or use indexes, but don't mix. Using iterators:

```
        for(Vector<T>::iterator i=&items[998]; i>=position; i--)
        {
            *(i+1)=*i;
        }
```

#### Edit :

[Just noticed an answer by Scheff that figured this out, after completing this edit]

The above invokes undefined behavior for `v.insert(v.begin(), value)` since `i` iterates before `items`. To avoid that, the iteration should stop before it falls off `items`:

```
        for(Vector<T>::iterator i=&items[999]; i > position; i--)
        {
            *i = *(i-1);
        }
```

Also, note that the line following the loop should also be fixed:

```
        items[*position]= item; // <--- BUG: also mixing indexes and iterators
```

---

Or using indexes:

```
        for(int i= 998; begin() + i>=position; i--)
        {
            items[i+1]=items[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of [Michael Veksler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52310211/7478597), I tried to get it working (and hence needed a bit longer).

So, with his first proposed fix and additionally

```
items[*position]= item;
```

changed to

```
*position = item;
```

the following test compiles and runs:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  Vector<double> vec;
  vec.insert(vec.begin(), 1.0);
  vec.insert(vec.begin(), 2.0);
  vec.insert(vec.begin(), 3.0);
  std::cout << "vec.size(): " << vec.size() << '\n';
  for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << "vec[" << i << "]: " << vec[i] << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
vec.size(): 0
```

Oops!

The update of `used` is missing in `insert()` as well:

```
++used;
```

And, now it looks better:

```
vec.size(): 3
vec[0]: 3
vec[1]: 2
vec[2]: 1
```

The complete [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Vector {
    public:
        typedef T* iterator;
        Vector () {  }

        T& operator[](unsigned int i) {
           return items[i];
        }
          // T& operator[](iterator i) {
           //return items[*i];
        //}

        iterator begin () {
            return &items[0];
        }
        iterator end () { 
            return &items[used];
        }
        int size () { return used; }

        iterator insert (iterator position, const T& item) { 

            for(Vector<T>::iterator i=&items[998]; i>=position; i--)
            {
                *(i+1) = *i;
            }
            *position = item;
            ++used;
            return position;
        }
    private:
        T items[1000];
        int used=0;
};

int main()
{
  Vector<double> vec;
  vec.insert(vec.begin(), 1.0);
  vec.insert(vec.begin(), 2.0);
  vec.insert(vec.begin(), 3.0);
  std::cout << "vec.size(): " << vec.size() << '\n';
  for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << "vec[" << i << "]: " << vec[i] << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22461e6723916524)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

So you can think of an iterator in this context as essentially a glorified pointer to the elements in the array, as you defined in your typedef at the beginning of your class.

When you're trying to access the elements in your array in your insert function, you are essentially dereferencing these pointers to yield the elements themselves and THEN using those elements as indices for your array, hence producing the error that the index is of the wrong type.

So for example suppose you had a `Vector<std::string>`. Inside the for loop in the insert function, you have this line:

```
items[*(i+1)]=items[*i];
```

Because `i` is an `iterator` as you defined, `i` has the type `std::string *` and hence `*i` has the type `std::string`. When you then write `items[*i]` you are trying to use the `std::string` as an index for your array which you can't do.

Instead, you should use a line similar to the following:

```
*(i + 1) = *i
```

There are also a couple of logical errors in your code, but I'll leave you to find those later on.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how [`std::move_backward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move_backward) can be implemented

```
template< class BidirIt1, class BidirIt2 >
BidirIt2 move_backward(BidirIt1 first, BidirIt1 last, BidirIt2 d_last)
{
    while (first != last) {
        *(--d_last) = std::move(*(--last));
    }
    return d_last;
}
```

You don't need to move any of the elements past `end`, and we can rewrite your `insert` to be similar

```
iterator insert (iterator position, const T& item) { 
    for(iterator i = end(), d = end() + 1; i != position; )
    {
        *(--d) = std::move(*(--i));
    }

    *position = item;
    ++used;

    return position;
}
```

Note that this is undefined if you try to insert into a full `Vector`